# WSDL & PHP. phpType is struct, but value is not an array

Tags: php, wsdl

I've been given the task of joining two ASP applications together to perform a variety of functions. Apparently as a PHP dev ASP is no worries, ha! I've had little problem till now but have hit this error and can't see the problem. As the title states when parsing a certain option in my call array (in this case 'org') I get 'phpType is struct, but value is not an array'.

My code

```
$result = $client->call('UserCreate',
                                array   (       'id'                    => '0',
                                                    'email'                 => 'josh@on.co.nz',
                                                'sendCreationEmail'     => 'TRUE',
                                                'role_id'               => 'Site Admin',
                                                'org'           => '2',
                                        )
                        );
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: You are not giving much to go on. Are you using NuSoap by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving much to go on. Are you using NuSoap by any chance?

I think your second parameter needs to be a nested array. Have not used this in ages but here is a sample soap call I had in my snippets:

```
 // call Web services function
 $result = $client->call('Report.QueueOvertime',               // function name
                    array('reportDescription' => array(
                               'reportSuiteID'=>'rsid',
                               'date'=>'2010-06-22',
                               'metrics'=>array(array('id'=>'pageViews')),
                               'locale'=>'en-US'),        // end reportDescription
                    'http://website.com',                // namespace
                    '',                                   // SOAP Action
                    get_header($username, $secret)        // security header
                 ); // end SOAP
```